# How to align three images side by side using CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to align these three images side by side and afer the div with id menu.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">...</div>      
<div class="l-grid">
    <ul>
        <li class="l-col l-size1of4">
            <div id="location">
                <img alt="Tell us your locaiton" src="images\location.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="l-col l-size1of4">
            <div id="delivery">
                <img alt="Choose menu to be delivered" src="images\dial\location.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="l-col l-size1of4">
            <div id="payment">
                <img alt="Payment mode" src="images\dial\payment.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.l-col {
    float: left;
}

.l-size1of4 {
    width: 166px;
}
```

adjacent pictures have to be in the page and after the div id main.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `ul li.l-col` to `display:inline-block`:

```
.l-col{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mR64t/

Answer (score 0):

Try using width for all  .l-col class,

```
 li.l-col {
            display: inline;
        }
```

**or**

```
.l-col {
            float: left;
            width: 166px;
        }
```